# Why is selenium grid becoming progressively slow?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have set up a grid of hub and nodes with selenium 2.40 server. I have windows 7 virtual machines as nodes and windows 2008 R2 server as the hub. I have 11 nodes per hub and I start the hub and nodes with following commands:

Hub:

```
java -Xmx500m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=false -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\\Windows\\Temp\\chromedriver.exe" -jar C:\Windows\Temp\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar -log C:\Windows\Temp\selenium\selLog.log -role hub -port 4444
```

Node:

```
java -Xmx500m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=false -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:\\Windows\\Temp\\chromedriver.exe" -jar C:\Windows\Temp\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-2.40.0.jar -log C:\Windows\Temp\selenium\selLog.log -role node -hub http://hub.mycompany.corp:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="firefox",maxInstances=5,firefox_binary=C:\Windows\Temp\Firefox\27.0.1\firefox.exe  -maxSession 5 -trustAllSSLCertificates -browserTimeout 200 -nodeTimeout 600
```

The set up works fine. I use C# api to run the tests. But the hub gets progressively slow to the point that after 10, 11 hours it takes more than a minute for it to respond to HTTP requests. It works fine right after deployment of hub.

Does anybody know what might be wrong? Or does everybody experience the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by AJ .

From one of the recent SeConf talks on selenium grid, Se team member mentioned the same problem. The easiest solution was to restart the machine once in a day if it is windows. If its linux it might run for may be a week before crashing. The culprit according to the se conf speaker was -Jetty server which is used in selenium and bad code.

You may try this https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras - it has got some cool features which might help you, like restarting nodes. Btw the author of this Selenium-Grid-Extras is the speaker at selcon.

Comment: Thanks for great answer. Damn! I wish I knew about this earlier. I have set up an scheduled task that checks the status of my hubs and nodes, takes them out f the load balancer and restart them if needed. Too much work and time wasted :/

Comment: This is interesting fact. So I test it my self. Note that I use windows for daily. Here's what I found:
(1) Grid, node = local windows, time = 30s
(2) Grid = ubuntu, node = local windows, time = 1m
(3) Grid = ubuntu, node = windows inside vm, time = 1m
(4) Grid, node = windows inside vm, time = 3m
Note that, windows inside vm is just the vm with the same operating system as my local (using VBox). The test is executed twice per scenario. The ubuntu is another vm hosted outside my local (using HyperV). So in my opinion, scenario (3) should be better than (4), but it doesn't. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Most of the people experience the same with selenium grid server on windows

**Long answer**

Windows and Selenium server is a bad combination compared to linux and selenium server. From one of the recent SeConf talks on selenium grid, Se team member mentioned the same problem. The easiest solution was to restart the machine once in a day if it is windows. If its linux it might run for may be a week before crashing. The culprit according to the se conf speaker was -Jetty server which is  used in selenium